# Unable to run cypress in docker reactjs project - Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, cypress

I spent two days just figuring out running cypress in a docker so I can test it locally. Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/base:16 as UIbuilder
ENV NODE_ENV development

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY custom-ui .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN npm pack

FROM cypress/base:16 as APPbuilder
ARG REACT_APP_PORTAL_API
ARG REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT="production"
ENV REACT_APP_PORTAL_API=$REACT_APP_PORTAL_API
ENV REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=$REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT

WORKDIR /opt/app
ENV APP_DIR /opt/app/

COPY . .

# Build App
COPY --from=UIbuilder /opt/app/*.tgz .
RUN npm install ./*.tgz --legacy-peer-deps
RUN chown -R node /opt/app/node_modules

RUN npm install
USER node


RUN npx cypress verify
# CMD ["ws", "--directory", ".", "--spa", "index.html", "--log.format", "combined"]
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And here is the docker-compose.dev.yml file

```
 version: "3.7"
 services:
  app:
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app:rw
      - /opt/app/node_modules
      - ./project-cypress/cypress:/opt/app/cypress
      - ./project-cypress/cypress.config.js:/opt/app/cypress.config.js
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://app
    command: npx cypress run
```

Here is the project directory is structured, a reactjs project

```
   frontend
      custom-ui
      build
      cypress
         e2e
         fixtures
         screenshots
         support
         videos
      public
      src
      ....
      cypress.config.js
```

Every time I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`
I got the following errors

```
Step 21/23 : RUN npx cypress verify
 ---> Running in 9c2b1398e724
No version of Cypress is installed in: /home/node/.cache/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress
Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install
----------
Cypress executable not found at: /home/node/.cache/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress/Cypress
----------
Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.3)
Cypress Version: 10.8.0
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c npx cypress verify' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any ideas about what I'm done wrong?

regards

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json file try to add

```
"cy:run": "cypress install && cypress run"
```

In a docker-compose.dev.yml file in the command section run cy:run.

> command: npm run cy:run

I know it's weird you may ask yourself why you should run a cypress install if you use a cypress image.. but I had the same problem, and this helped me.